# Systemd service on java script which has to be ran from a working folder

Tags: scripting, systemd

I have a java application installed on ubuntu 20.04 server, which is started up with a JJS command-line script file, like this:

```
#!../lib/bin/jre/bin/jjs -scripting function myJAVA(c){ bala bala bala ......}
```

Usually to start this application up, following below 2 steps needed:

```
# cd /my_app_path/MsgPro/bin
# ./myJAVA start
```

Obviously I need go to the bin folder then run the script from there, otherwise(if runs from other folder) there is bellow error.

```
bash: ./bin/msgProcessor: ../lib/bin/jre/bin/jjs: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I know nothing about java, however then was asked to create a myJAVA.service via systemctl, this will ensure that the application is restarted automatically when the server reboots or unexpected exit.

I know a unit file in /etc/system/systemd/myJAVA.service will do this, but no idea how to make it works, below is my unit file.

```
[Unit]
Description=myJAVA Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root

Environment=PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
ExecStart=/my_app_path/MsgPro/bin/myJAVA start

Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I guess my ExecStart or Environment was wrong, but don't know the correct ones.

Any helps are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your script set the first line:

```
#!../lib/bin/jre/bin/jjs
```

to be absolute path, not relative (if this is the interpreter)
If you just want to run your program make your script like this:

```
....../lib/bin/jre/bin/jjs -scripting function myJAVA(c){ bala bala bala ......}
```

again set absolute path to program

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `WorkingDirectory=` to emulate `cd <path> && ./script`.
2. Usually, we don't need `WorkingDirectory=` unless we are specifying a place to write (doesn't apply to `bin`). If you can change your scripts to use absolute paths, or paths relative to an environment variable, that often solves a lot of these issues.
3. You usually don't need to set `$PATH`.  Use absolute paths in systemd units, and if you run a shell script, that script will often set `PATH` itself through something like `.bashrc`.
4. You don't need `User=root`.  That's already implied on the systemd service bus.

This service should work for you:

```
[Unit]
Description=myJAVA Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/my_app_path/MsgPro/bin
ExecStart=/my_app_path/MsgPro/bin/myJAVA start

Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- You were on the right track with `ExecStart=/absolute/path`. That is sure to run your script.
- `WorkingDirectory=` will let your script find things that are designed to be relative to your bin (`../lib/bin/jre/bin/jjs`).